# Customizing Woocommerce template my-account/form-edit-addresses

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Having some issues with the address area of `/my-account/edit-addresses/`

1. I would like to customize the form fields within the template `form-edit-addresses.php`. For example, I would like to change for all the fields, plus individually place some within separate classes:

```html
<p class="form-row form-row-first validate-required" id="billing_first_name_field" data-priority="10">
<label for="billing_first_name" class="">First name <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" placeholder="" value="Name"></p>
```

to

```html
<div class="form-group form-group-default input-group">
<div class="form-input-group">
<label for="billing_first_name" class="">Company</label>
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" placeholder="" value="Name">
</div>
```

Please note that these above are just the HTML tags taken from the inspect and are not the correct fields as to make the form work. That I can handle - it's just finding or replacing the fields.

[image: This is the current Layout that is not very adaptable to my needs]

[image: This is what I require the form to look like using the tags above]

2. The second thing I would like to accomplish is to add this form within the `/my-account/edit-addresses/` URL/Slug rather than `/my-account/edit-addresses/billing`
3. The third is to make the form upon submitting redirect to `/my-account/` instead of `/my-account/edit-addresses/` and include any Woocommerce notices
4. The last point is to remove the `First Name` `Last Name` `Email` `Phone` fields. I assume will fix easily by completing step 1 and removing the form fields that are not required.

Greatly appreciate any time given to finding solutions to these.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can NOT change the `<p>` tag (removing all existing attributes + values) to a `<div>` as will certainly break some processes, because specific woocommerce javascript is enabled on this…

Now you can use **`woocommerce_form_field_args`** filter hook to change the **class** globally on all the `<p>` tags and you can remove the **required** behavior on all the fields too, so **`<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr>`** will be removed.

Here is that code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_args', 'custom_wc_form_field_args', 10, 3 );
function custom_wc_form_field_args( $args, $key, $value ){
    // Only on My account > Edit Adresses
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-account' ) || is_checkout() ) return $args;

    $args['class'] = array('form-input-group');
    $args['required'] = false;

    return $args;
}
```

So you will have to manage CSS to make design changes.

All available arguments $args in this array are:

```
'type'              # @ string
'label'             # @ string
'description'       # @ string
'placeholder'       # @ string
'maxlength'         # @ boolean
'required'          # @ boolean
'autocomplete'      # @ boolean
'id'                # => $key (argument)
'class'             # @ array
'label_class'       # @ array
'input_class'       # @ array
'return'            # @ boolean
'options'           # @ array
'custom_attributes' # @ array
'validate'          # @ array
'default'           # @ string
'autofocus'         # @ string
'priority'          # @ string
```

With `woocommerce_form_field_{field_type}` filter hook you can access to field settings individually based on the field type. This hook has 4 available arguments: `$field`, `$key`, `$args` and `$value`…

Comment: Thank you very much. However, ignore removing the <p> as you have rightfully shown this class to be editable. I need a <div class="form-group"> between the opening <p> and the <label>. In addition, I need to add a class to the Input. Cannot find a fix anywhere. Any additional help is appreciated.

Comment: I have now completed what I wanted with some sacrifice to the layout. All in all, thank you for your help. Whilst I did not apply it this time I did use as the foundation of the fix. I generally get lazy looking at the functions.php and waste much time looking for alternative solutions. When shall I learn = )

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Hi; I tried to change the priority of billing_address_1 to after state and city fields . I set up `switch ($key) {
        case 'billing_state' :
            $args['priority'] = '45';
            break;
        case 'billing_city' :
            break;
        case 'billing_address_1' :
            $args['priority'] = '190';
            break;
        default:
            break;`
but it Doesn't affect the rows priority. I don't have any Idea .

Answer (score 3):

I have figured out part 2, 3 and 4 of my question - just in case someone else was looking...

Part 2 was to add the `form-edit-address.php` to `edit-address`

I added this to the `my-address.php` template

```
<?php
// get the user meta
$userMeta = get_user_meta(get_current_user_id());

// get the form fields
$countries = new WC_Countries();
$billing_fields = $countries->get_address_fields( '', 'billing_' );
$shipping_fields = $countries->get_address_fields( '', 'shipping_' );
?>

<!-- billing form -->
<?php
$load_address = 'billing';
$page_title   = __( 'Billing Address', 'woocommerce' );
?>
<form action="/my-account/edit-address/billing/" class="edit-account" method="post">

    <h2><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_edit_address_title', $page_title ); ?></h2>

    <?php do_action( "woocommerce_before_edit_address_form_{$load_address}" ); ?>

    <?php foreach ( $billing_fields as $key => $field ) : ?>

        <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $userMeta[$key][0] ); ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php do_action( "woocommerce_after_edit_address_form_{$load_address}" ); ?>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="save_address" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save Address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-edit_address' ); ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="edit_address" />
    </p>

</form>
```

To do part 3 and redirect submit from `form-edit-address.php` I added the following to my theme `functions.php`

```
function action_woocommerce_customer_save_address( $user_id, $load_address ) { 
   wp_safe_redirect(wc_get_page_permalink('myaccount')); 
   exit;
}; 
add_action( 'woocommerce_customer_save_address', 'action_woocommerce_customer_save_address', 99, 2 );
```

To do part 4 and remove fields from the `form-edit-address.php` I added the following to my theme `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields' , 'custom_override_billing_fields' );

function custom_override_billing_fields( $fields ) {
  unset($fields['billing_first_name']);
  unset($fields['billing_last_name']);
  unset($fields['billing_phone']);
  unset($fields['billing_email']);
  return $fields;
}
```

Any help with the other part of this question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not a problem. I too believe the question is too broad but I dare not delete it because I found your answer and mine rather helpful. I might just delete these comments though now we have the other thing wrapped up. Have a great day.

Comment: This has been very helpful. It's been 4 years since, are there any other options to add the billing and shipping forms to the bottom of the account page?